# Can 'fall' be a linking verb?

Tags: linking-verbs

Linking verbs

> do not describe any direct action taken or controlled by the subject.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linking_verb

Can "fall" be a linking verb, so that in e.g.

> No-one *has* fell out the window

could "out the window" be a predicate adjective, rather than a prepositional phrase? The phrase may just seem like bad grammar. But it seems to have a different sense to "no-one has fallen out the window",. I think this version has more immediacy to it; that could be because it is incorrect grammar / informal, or perhaps because it redefines what has happened?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117467/discussion-on-question-by-anon-can-fall-be-a-linking-verb).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can, but it isn't a linking verb where you use it.

A linking verb is a verb that connects the subject with a subject-complement, which by definition can only be a nominal phrase or adjective.

As it stands:

> He has fallen **ill**.

> He fell **dead**.

And many others are possible, using “fall” as a linking verb.

Like many linking verbs in English that are also used as unaccusative verbs without a complement, this one can only take adjectives as complement it seems, and not nominal phrases, thus:

> *He has fallen **an ill man**.

Does not work, with say “become” or “be”, nominal phrases can also be used.